# Refused to display in a frame becasue it sets X-frame-options to DENY?

Tags: single-sign-on, yammer, x-frame-options

I am using Single sing on in my project using Microsoft login now I am trying to use yammer embed on this site but it is giving the following error.

**Refused to display** https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?   client_id=xxxx&login_hint=&nonce=xxxx&nux=1&prompt=none&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fpersona.yammer.com%2F office_sessions%3Fon_error%3Dhttps%3A%2F%2Fwww.yammer.com%2Fplatform_embed%2Foffice_login_error&response_mode=query&response_type=id_token&scope=open_id&site_id=xxxx&state=xxxx **in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY'**

can anybody help me with this.

Comment: Please post the code you are putting in the page to enable Yammer Embed. It's likely you have "use_sso: true" which is causing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is an intentional behaviour - normally Identity Providers will refuse to display login page within an iframe due to security reasons. You should use either pop-up or in-place redirect.